# Service data binding, trouble to get $apply within $watch to run

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to set up a very simple AngularJS app, but I have trouble getting my `$watch` and `$apply` to run.

I just (for now) want to display the length of an Array which I receive in a JSON object. I set up a watcher to bind my Service-data to view and put an $apply call into it, but somehow this doesn't work.

When removing the `$apply()` my view is updating, but it's updating the previous value (hence I suppose everything else works as supposed).

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="scandataCtrl">
    {{scandata.length}}
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
app.controller('scandataCtrl',['$scope', 'DataHandler', function($scope, DataHandler) {

    $scope.scandata = DataHandler.getScanData();

    $scope.$watch(
        function(){
            return DataHandler.getScanData();
        }, 
        function(newVal, oldVal){
            $scope.$apply(function(){
                $scope.scandata = DataHandler.getScanData();
            });
    });

}]);


app.service('DataHandler', function() 
{
    var scanresult = [];

    this.getScanData = function()
    {
        return scanresult;
    };

    this.msgreceive = function(msg)
    {
        var msgobj = JSON.parse(msg);
        switch (msgobj.MessageType)
        {
            case 'SCANRESULT':
                scanresult = msgobj.MessageData.myArray;
                break;
            default:
                alert("error: undefined message received")
                break;
        }
    };
});
```

I googled a lot but coudn't figure it out.

Comment: It's unclear what you expect to happen and what happens instead. But you don't need $apply at all. Just do `$scope.scandata = newVal;`

Comment: Well, I am initiating a Websocket message-request by clicking on a button. After reveiving the answer I want to update my view immidiately but instead it's updating after another click on the button - and thus updating an 'old' value

Comment: Then you need to call $apply() in the function receiving the message and modifying the state of your service without angular knowing. Not in your watcher. A watcher can't detect any change if it hasn't been made using $apply() before.

Comment: Thanks! adding $rootScope.$apply in 'SCANRESULT' case of DataHandler-Service is working!

Answer (score -1):

You should use `$timeout` instead of `$apply`:

```
$scope.$watch(function(){
    return DataHandler.getScanData();
}, function(newVal, oldVal){
    $timeout(function(){
        $scope.scandata = DataHandler.getScanData();
    });
});
```

Timeout will internally call `$apply` but in a safe manner which will not throw an exception of **digest is already in progress**.

Comment: @downvoter, can you please explain what is the problem here instead of just down voting.

Comment: Can you please provide a plunkr or fiddle reproducing this problem.

Comment: I wanted, but I didn't know how to simulate the websocket functionality to achieve the asynchronous behavior

Comment: You can provide a button in the UI to manually update data in your service (just for the sake of mocking it).

Comment: Well, searching **mock websocket** gave me the first link https://github.com/thoov/mock-socket. You can try that if you have time

Comment: I tried to do it with a simple button, but it does not reproduce the Problem. That websocket mock might do it, but I dont have time to try it right now, sorry

Comment: Not a problem at all @Draz